# How can I set brightness in openlayers 3.11....?

Tags: openlayers

Current version of OL 3 is 3.11.2 , I've seen in old example (3.8) there is support for brightness / contrast :
http://openlayers.org/en/v3.8.1/examples/brightness-contrast.html

But newer versions don't support such feature.

Any ways to affect the layers brightness/contrast ?

Answer (score 1):

This is what it says in the upgrade notes:

The experimental `setHue`, `setContrast`, `setBrightness`, `setSaturation`, and the corresponding getter methods have been removed.  These properties only worked with the WebGL renderer.  If are interested in applying color transforms, look for the `postcompose` event in the API docs.  In addition, the `ol.source.Raster` source provides a way to create new raster data based on arbitrary transforms run on any number of input sources.

Comment: Sorry , I didn't understand this answer. Is there a chance for an example how to do such a task ? I've tried to look for the API and didn't see.

My goal is to set the base layer darker when user is outside in the sun and want darker image

Comment: Can you point me to an example which will help me do such task ?

Comment: @Alophind any workaround for this ?